# Neural network for an output in the form of a probability distribution

Tags: neural-networks, probability-distribution, performance

I am not an expert in machine learning. Recently, I want to construct a data-driven model based the neural network. The problem is that I want from my algorithm to learn an output in the form of a probability distribution (maybe to learn the parameters of a predefined probability distribution). This is because the phenomenon I am trying to model is highly uncertain.
In my case, I am dealing with a supervised learning. Hence, the output which is supposedly in form of a probability distribution should be compared with data points to assess the performance. Could you please suggest to me a reference dealing with this issue.
Thank you so much for your valuable help.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the distribution that you want to learn? Do you want to learn any distribution? Do you know that regular neural networks for classification produce a probability vector? I don't think that's what you want though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that stochasticity is an intrinsic property of my system so I need to model it explicitly (regression rather than classification). I want my system to learn for example the parameters of a normal distribution. Regular neural networks  produce a probability vector but I think perhaps this is not a property of the 'law' govening the data exactly.